# Low level Elastic search usage in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch

I am using Elastic search 7.1 and I would like to avoid using NEST. My question is : Is there a detailed tutorial or resource with examples (except official documentation) which covers working with Elastic search using low level interface such is ElasticSearch.net and where can I find it ?
Documentation must include examples and code calls strictly from .NET.

Thanks

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/elasticsearch-net.html

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Elasticsearch.Net